# Webpack ReactJS file creation

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am trying out ReactJS with Webpack, hot updating, and React-Router. Below is my 
webpack.config.js code. For some reason there are a bunch of json files being created at the very top of the file tree. For example, fb43026df6c9e1823c07.hot-update.json

Files end with .hot-update.json

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000',
  'webpack/hot/dev-server',
  './scripts/index'
],
output: {
path: __dirname,
filename: 'bundle.js',
publicPath: '/static/'
},
resolve: {
extensions: ['', '.js']
},
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
plugins: [
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
],
module: {
loaders: [
  {
   test: /\.js$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   loaders: ['babel-loader']
  },
  {
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
  },
  {
   test: /\.jsx?$/,
   loaders: ['babel'],
   include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
  }
 ]
 }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the file that Webpack's hotModuleReplacementPlugin is reading from every time you make a change and save it. It's making new bundles of your app for your front end to receive.